# How to intersect GeoJSON's with two shapefiles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson, shapefile, qgis

I've got a task where I need to find information about some polygons (.GeoJSON) that intersect with another two shapefiles (mesoregions and Landsat tiles).

I need to know which mesoregion and tile each one of the polygons is 100% inserted. I've already done it manually trough Qgis, but would like to try to do it using Python at Jupyter Notebook.

I'm a newbie at programming so I haven't done much code because I don't know where to start. Would like to know if anyone could please help me with it?

Here it is what I've done so far:

```
import os
import glob
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path1='/home/Desktop/Geojson_4_monitoring/file.GeoJSON'
path2='/home/Desktop/grid_sentinel2_BR/grid_sentinel2_BR.shp'
path3='/home/Desktop/br_mesoregions/br_mesoregions.shp'

polygons= path1
token= path2
meso= path3

df_token=gpd.read_file(token)
df_meso=gpd.read_file(meso)
df_polygons=gpd.read_file(polygons)

polygons_tokens = gpd.sjoin(df_meso,df_token, how="inner", op='intersects')
```

Than i get the following error message: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'"

Initially I was trying to do it for a folder with some .GeoJSON's, but I still do not know pretty well how to make for loops. So I decided to try doing it just for 1 .GeoJSON file.

Anyways, hope this help to clear out what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the attention guys!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow it is expected that you have written code already and present it with your question. "How to start?" questions are considered too broad for this format.